# How can I copy text from Vuetify's v-text-field to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using **Vuetify** and trying to copy text from `v-text-field` component to clipboard when button is clicked. [`Sample code available on codepen`](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/abowjpJ?&editable=true&editors=101):

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container>
          <v-text-field v-model="text1"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn @click="copyText">copy</v-btn>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data() { 
        return {
          text1: 'lorem ipsum 123'
        }
      },
      methods: {
        copyText (){
          // copy to clipboard
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

The question is what code to put in `copyText` method of the Vue instance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do it by assigning a value to `ref` attribute and then in the method request the `input` element, select its content using `select` function and copy that content using `document.execCommand("copy");`:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container>
          <v-text-field v-model="text1" ref="textToCopy"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn @click="copyText">copy</v-btn>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data() { 
        return {
          text1: 'lorem ipsum 123'
        }
      },
      methods: {
        copyText () {
          let textToCopy = this.$refs.textToCopy.$el.querySelector('input')
          textToCopy.select()
          document.execCommand("copy");
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to decouple copyText() method from $refs or css id of an element? 

Eg. I have an array of strings that are dynamically rendered with `v-text-field` by using `v-for`. I'd like to add 'copy' button next to each of these `v-text-field`. Then when button is clicked I'd like just the text from its associated `v-text-field` to be copied to clipboard.

Comment: Also, I added a couple of code after `execCommand` to reset a selection in input:
`const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
selection.removeRange(range);`

Answer (score 32):

This solution worked for me. It uses the new [Clipboard API writeText method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) which is supported by most modern browsers (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext) for more details). Writing to the clipboard does not require special permissions.

```
  methods: {
    copyText() {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.text1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved with vue-clipboards.

1.- npm install vue-clipboards 

2.- add this in your main.js

```
import VueClipboards from 'vue-clipboards'
Vue.use(VueClipboards)
```

3.- Create vuetify btn and add v-clipboard like below

```
<v-btn v-clipboard="clipboardValue">add to clipboard</v-btn>
```

4.- In your data section (you can fill your var in any method or where you want).

```
data: () => ({
clipboardValue: 'something'
}),
```

5.- Run your code. its all.

Comment: Probably the smoothest way to copy text. Preferring this over writing methods again and again for each component.

Answer (score 1):

This does not requrie any kind of third party library
Just Pass Dynamic String Using On click method

```
<template>
     <v-btn @click="copyToClipBoard(errorMsg)">
       <v-icon>mdi-content-copy</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
</template>
```

method will copy it to clipboard directly

```
  methods: {
    copyToClipBoard(textToCopy) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the `v-text-field` element like :

```
   <v-text-field v-model="text1" id="tocopy" ></v-text-field>
```

and add the following code to your method :

```
copyText(){
    let input=document.getElementById("tocopy");
   input.select();
         document.execCommand("copy");
    }
```

check this [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/yLBXqKO?editors=1011)

Comment: You have to change ref= to id=. Vuetify obviously remaps it to a real input element, ref doesnt get remapped, im sure there is a way to get a real ref to work.