# Copy <pre> tag content to clipboard on on Vue.js App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, google-chrome-extension, copy

Im working on a chrome extension vue app where my goal is to copy the content of the pre tag section to clipboard with a click of a button. I have defined an element ID to the pre tag so i can grab the content using a copyToClipboard() method. My code is like so:

```
<template>
        <div>
          <button @click="copyToClipboard()">Copy To Clipboard</button>
        </div>
```

Method is defined like this:

```
methods : {
copyToClipboard() {
      const textToCopy = document.getElementById('textToBecopied')
      textToCopy.select()
      document.execCommand('copy')
    }
}
```

I think the method is executing correctly but the function that I'm using as .select throws an error that it's not a function. Anyone has a better idea to achieve what im looking for?

[image]

Comment: Follow this link for solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830678/10538842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by getting the pre-tag content and copying it to a dummy text area, and then I was able to use the select method as well as the copy to clipboard function.

```
copyToClipboard() {
  const copyText = document.getElementById('textToBecopied').textContent
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
  textArea.textContent = copyText
  document.body.append(textArea)
  textArea.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HTMLInputElement.select()` method selects all the text in a `<textarea>` element or in an `<input>` element that includes a text field.

`document.getElementById('textToBecopied')` - is a `<pre>` element.

Use `Node.textContent` to get the text. And for copying to the clipboard - [**Clipboard API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: yes "document.getElementById('textToBecopied')" is the <pre> tag content that im storing into variable textToCopy. Not sure where you are saying to use Node.textContent

Comment: @jfr01 , "document.getElementById('textToBecopied')" - it is not the content of the <pre> tag, but the tag itself, which does not have a .select() method.